# My reputation has increased-- do all the downvotes I made before I had 125 reputation now have an effect on displayed score of q's and a's?

Tags: support

My reputation has increased-- do all the downvotes I made before I had 125 reputation now have an effect on displayed score of q's and a's?

If not, can I go back and recast those votes even if no editing has taken place to those q's and a's?

Just trying to figure out how this all works--

Answer (score 3):

You can't downvote if you're <125 rep points, if you've tried it, you should have noticed a banner that says it doesn't count. I also wouldn't go crazy with the downvotes just because you can. It's better to leave a comment requesting clarification or suggesting a correction.

Downvotes on answers remove 1 rep per vote from you, the voter. It's one way to verify, check [your reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/34686/quiet-flyer?tab=reputation) or [your recorded votes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/34686/?tab=votes). Only you can view -1 changes and your votes tab.

For more info on downvoting, check the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).